# Joomla Xmap Implode Error on Sitemap

Tags: php, joomla, implode, invalid-argument

I am getting the following error on an 'xmap' sitemap plugin used on Joomla v2.5 with the K2 cck on one of my sites as below:

**Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/anctest/public_html/plugins/xmap/com_k2/com_k2.php on line 192**

Its pointing to the following line in the below code:

```
$query = $baseQuery."catid in (".implode(",", $ids).") order by 1 DESC ";
```

Code here:

```
        case "categories":
            if (!self::$suppressSub)
            {
                $query = $baseQuery."catid in (".implode(",", $ids).") order by 1 DESC ";
                $db->setQuery($query);
                $rows = $db->loadObjectList ();
            }
            else 
            {
                $rows = array();
                if (is_array($ids))
                {
                    foreach($ids as $id)
                    {
                        $allrows = array();
                        xmap_com_k2::collectByCat($db, $id, $allrows);
                        $rows = array_merge($rows, $allrows);
                    }       
                }
            }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ids not an array
`file_put_contents('log.txt',var_export($ids,true));` or `var_dump($ids)`
$ids in this case gets from link parameters in menu. Maybe categories not selected for this link. `var_dump($parent->link)` will show you all links, and a link before the error will be the problem link.